# How to load a JSF page after file upload?

Tags: java, jsf

what i want is to load another page after performing a fileUpload.

I tried to put this code in the bean which process the fileupload:

```
return "<JSF Page Name>?faces-redirect=true"
```

but still no luck...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't navigate from inside an action **listener** method. You can only navigate from inside a real **action** method, the one which is bound to the `action` attribute of an `UICommand` component.

You can however send a redirect programmatically by [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("page.xhtml");
```